# Django DRF views filter ManyToMany queryset

Tags: django, view, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

There are two models, `class User(Model)` and

```
class Loan(Model):
    parents = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='parents', verbose_name='Родители') # .objects.all().filter(user_type=User.PARENT)
    children = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='children', verbose_name='Дети') #.objects.all().filter(user_type=User.CHILD)
```

and view based on DRF

```
class ChildrenViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        # TODO here i need to write filter
        return queryset
```

How I can filter the queryset to select all children for defined parent?

I have some `parent_identity` (can be called `id` or `pk`)

What I expect to see:

```
queryset = User.objects.filter(children__loan_set__parent__identoty=parent_identity)
return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

DONE

```
class ChildrenViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = auth_models.User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = auth_serializers.UserModelSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = auth_models.User.objects.all()

        parent_identity = self.request.query_params.get('parent', None)
        if parent_identity is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(children__parents__identity=parent_identity) |
                Q(children__parents__email=parent_identity) |
                Q(children__parents__phone=parent_identity)
            )
        return queryset
```